Should we use Persistent Volumes for databases in Kubernetes?
I think this is something that must have been asked earlier but I could not find a complete explanation of why persistent volumes should not be used for databases (using Postgres in my case) in Kubernetes
I saw videos about the data consistency aspects and the race conditions stuff . So I read up on stateful sets and the master slave approaches. But almost everyone was suggesting to use stateful sets in some way which I didnot understand why?
Some said to just probably not do it as K8S is by design still stateless on many parts.
The current approach in my head is something like this - (NOT EXACTLY MASTER SLAVE)
Use somewhat of a master-slave like using 1 master to only write, multiple slaves to only read, and both just share a persistent volume. Then there should not be a need for the replication stream or for the databases to interact I guess.
This seemed very intuitive but I havent seen anyone mentioning this approach, so I am doubting I am missing something very obvious.
Feel free to point out mistakes, link articles or stuff.
